# Open a text file in NotePad with single instance

Tags: c#, winforms, file, c#-4.0, notepad

In my project, I am trying to open a text file. Well the below code works but when the user click the button again and again, many files are being opened. (which I dont want)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420484/1577396), `File.Open` and `File.OpenText` which are not opening the text file and also not showing any error (tried with try catch block)

```
File.Open(filePath); (or)
File.OpenText(filePath); (or)
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
```

I also tried this: (*ERROR* : Cannot be accessed with instance reference qualify with a type name instead)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.Start(filePath);  /*red scribbles here*/
proc.WaitForExit();
```

How to show only one instance of the Text file(.txt). Am I doing something wrong in my attempts? please suggest.

**EDIT:**

I want to open other text files afterwards but not the same and also the application should be accessible after opening a text file(or many). I have only one form.

Comment: Define what you mean by "Open". Do you want to open it in Notepad?

Comment: next questions:
1) do you need to open multiple text files at the same time (one window for each file); 2) does your application need to keep doing something while the text file is open?

Comment: Hmm.. just disable the button after first click?

Comment: the text files should open multiple but unique.... my application need to keep doing something while the text file is open :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard no I want to open other text files (not same) afterwards

Comment: @Mr_Green So assuming you want to open each file only once, add class member that store the files already opened (e.g. in a `List<string>`) then when clicking the button, if the file chosen exists in that class member show alert instead of opening the file.

Comment: Seems you have no way but reflecting on running processes, fishing notepads and see if you can get the filename somehow.

Comment: You're going to have to check yourself whether a particular file has been opened by maintaining a list of already opened files.

Comment: Regarding solution to your current problem : do not open a file if it is already opened by same application. (not to your question=> check if a file is already opened) An easy way is to store filepath of each file in a `List<sting>` check your `filepath` if it does not already exists open it and add its path to list.

Comment: Okay I will do that on my own (actually I can) I need only solution for having single instance of the text with access to the application. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green - see my answer - by storing the previously opened processes by file path you can make sure that each file is opened only once.

Comment: The whole 'maintaining a file list' isn't going to work. Users can, and will, just close notepad without letting your list know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dictionary at the form level:

```
public Dictionary<string, Process> OpenedProcesses = new Dictionary<string, Process>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Now change how you open the file (note the `HasExited` check - this is needed so that the user can close the Notepad and reopen it):

```
// make sure that path is always in form C:\Folder\file.txt - less chance of different 
// paths pointing to the same file.
filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath);

Process proc;
if (this.OpenedProcesses.TryGetValue(filePath, out proc) && !proc.HasExited)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The file is already open!");
    // it could be possible to activate the window of the open process but that is another question on its own.
    return;
}

proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
this.OpenedProcesses[filePath] = proc;
```

Comment: It's bad because OP stated user should be able to continue his things while file is open.

Comment: @avip, OP stated that after my answer. also the answer was updated after OP clarified it.

Comment: Yes this worked.. thank you very much for showing great effort.

Comment: +1 for the nice idea. Better than all other proposed alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is opened

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427265/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-check-if-a-excel-file-is-opened)

and then do your work as you want.